Standard method of CVR aggregation
We are using GA4 to collect extended e-commerce events (home-page-view, view-item-list,detail-page-view, add-to-cart,purchase-complete, etc.).
I want to aggregate as accurately as possible the Conversion Rate (CVR) of a particular user's actions within an e-commerce site,
Does anyone know of a standard way to track user behavior?
I know that GA4's reporting functionality can be used for aggregation,
I have heard that it includes random sampling values and predicted values.
I am wondering if the tabulation by GA4's report function is accurate.
Also, I know that the data collected by GA4 can be aggregated by BigQuery.
If I use BigQuery, what kind of SQL should I create?
I tried to get a tally by GA4, but found that it did not seem to be accurate.
